# What causes spike in branch predictions Vtune

Tags: windows, profiling, branch-prediction, intel-vtune

I am launching an application using VTune and profiling it. Once the test is run, I see a spike in branch prediction unit.

To optimize my application, I need to figure out what part of the code causes this spike. Is there a way through VTune I can figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

To understand what code causes branch miss-predicts: switch to Bottom-pp pane to see profile by functions and sort by branch miss-predicts column. This way functions with the most number of miss-predicts will be on top. Double-clicking on function will dive you to Source View where you'll be able to see distribution of miss-predicts by source lines or even assembly instructions.